# Ubuntu recovery mode. How to get backup of my home and download directories

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, backup, recovery-mode

I am having a disaster. My Ubuntu can not boot. The problem is summarised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098366/ubunut-18-04-failed-to-boot-faile-to-start-mysql-community-server)

I read about Ubunut recovery mode. I followed these [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). I selected `Drop to root shell promot`. I got a shell in the bottom. It has the followign text:

```
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Contol-D to continue):
root@mypc-name:~#
```

There is a cursos blinking. When I type `pwd` it prints: `/root`

I need to recover my data to an external hard disk. Please help me in a step by step. I use Ubuntu in GUI. I use the terminal but I have no experience in mounting and working with hard disks and moving data using the shell.

Please note that I have 0 Bytes available in my hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those tried to help. I solved the issue by following the same steps in the question to use recovery mode. Then I choose `Clean` (instead of `Drop to root shell prompt`). This provided few hundreds MB which allowed me to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make comments, but I want to help anyway.

You should try booting a live ubuntu disc/USB and select "Try without installing".. You'll get a fully working environment and automounting for your HDD and external drives. While at it you can delete at least a couple files to make some room and you'll be able to boot again