# Ubuntu 18.04 failed to boot due to Failed to start MySQL community server

Tags: boot, 18.04, mysql

I met a problem with Ubuntu 18.04 that can not boot:

```
Failed to start MySQL community server
```

Can't remember exactly how the problem started, but it seems related to update/installation some pkgs including php7. Some clues are:

1) An upgrade from 'Buster' to 'Bionic' is not supported with this release, which seems to be Ubuntu 18.04.4 was mixed up with Debian release.

2) /etc/rc0 (? Maybe inaccurate. It flashed away too fast)no such file or directory, do not understand this at all.

3) Tried the "recovery mode" method, no luck.

[There is another report of the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098366/ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-boot-faile-to-start-mysql-community-server/1226612#1226612), but I especially do not understand how MySQL impacted the kernel/booting.

I tried different ways without any luck. Really wish to get some help from the forum. Thanks!

Comment: Normally, tis comes with the comment `See 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.`  did you do that? Could you post the result?

Comment: @Marc Thanks! The system even could not boot, so that I can't check the status of MySQL. Anyway, I re-installed the system thru the fix broken system with the LiveCD.